# How to get values from a nested JSON string with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON string which is outputed by:

```
{
       "event":"build",
       "tab":"map",
       "selection":{
          "tier":{
             "id":1,
             "parentId":0,
             "label":"ca",
             "level":100,
             "hashKey":"object:5"
          },
          "group":{
             "id":2,
             "parentId":1448818,
             "label":"com",
             "spatialLevelId":203,
             "hashKey":"object:11"
          },
          "area":{
             "id":3,
             "parentId":1449705,
             "label":"cam",
             "level":303,
             "hashKey":"object:14"
          },
          "indicators":[

          ]
       }
    }
```

How can I get the level only from all 3 sections (tier, group, area) and put them into a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the values like following

```
function handler(message) {
     var tierSpatialLevelId = message.selection.tier.spatialLevelId; 
     var groupSpatialLevelId = message.selection.group.spatialLevelId;
     var areaSpatialLevelId = message.selection.area.spatialLevelId; 
}
```